# How to import .ipr file for configuring Apache Kafka with Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug Kafka's source code with IntelliJ IDEA and for that I have to setup the IDE first. The official documentation of Kafka provides with the steps and so far, I have completed all of them to run Kafka from the source.

Then there is a step named [Building IDE Project](https://github.com/kebab-mai-haddi/kafka#building-ide-project) which has the command:

```
./gradlew idea
```

The output of the above successful command is:

```
> Configure project :
Starting build with version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT using Gradle 6.8.3, Java 1.8 and Scala 2.13.5

> Task :idea
Generated IDEA project at file:///Users/aviralsrivastava/dev/kafka/kafka.ipr
```

I installed Intellij IDEA but unable to figure out how do I import the above file and what purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open the ipr file from File menu

However, as the docs state

> Note that this is not strictly necessary (IntelliJ IDEA has good built-in support for Gradle projects, for example).

You can just open the root `build.gradle` file in Intellij, and it'll prompt you to import the folder as a project